# Getting navigated to the end of the Mobile app page,altough I have used swipe function to navigate till a particular locator

Tags: swipe, opentest

I have used code

- description: Swipe down in search of the Pagination button
  action: org.getopentest.appium.Swipe
  args:
  direction: down
  target: $data($localData.platformName + "/ExploreLocators").Pagination.Range

Also, tried with

- description: Verify the case studies tab is visible
  action: org.getopentest.appium.AssertElementVisible
  args:
  locator: $data($localData.platformName + "/ExploreLocators").Pagination.Range
  swipe : down

But everytime, i'm getting swiped till end of the screen

Answer (score 0):

This issue is probably resolved in the meantime, but posting this for other people that might have the same issue.
This behavior can have two causes:

- The element is really not in the page
- The element locator is incorrect (which is actually more likely the cause)

In both cases, OpenTest will continue scrolling to the end of the page in search of the UI element. Please read the error message in the test session log and see what is the locator being used, then make sure the locator is correct and the UI element is actually in the page and is visible.